# MonoMac or Monobjc

Tags: macos, mono, monomac, monobjc

I need to port a .Net application from Windows to OS X and I am wondering what are the advantageous and disadvantageous of using either Monobjc or MonoMac and what peoples experience with these are.

**App Requirements**

1. Native UI
2. Scripting Bridge (or alternative) for Inter-application Communication will need to be both ways i.e. calling the ported application from another and having another application call the ported application.
3. Growl integration for notifications.

What would be the best option considering the requirements above.

Comment: Bill the Lizard - you are a lizzard that does not understand a thing - you should not be a moderator because you are a lizzard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For item 1 if you carefully read the below article, you will see why MonoMac was born and why you should now use it,

http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Apr-19.html

After these two years, MonoMac has already grown to be a giant in this field. Unless you are maintaining an old project built upon other bindings, you should consider MonoMac as your first option.

It does not matter whether you use MonoMac or another binding, as the last two items are not closely related to item 1.

For IPC you can consider WCF (limited support from Mono), Thrift (http://thrift.apache.org/) and many others.

Growl is not a Mac OS X API. For such vendor specific stuffs you should consult the vendor.

Comment: ok so how do I go about making my application scriptable so that it can be called from other applications using MonoMac?

Comment: Updated with what you would like to know.